# How to change the content of Variables called in Template file of Prestashop

Tags: smarty, prestashop

banners.tpl files code snippet

```
{if !empty($banner.html)}
<div class="custom-html">
{$banner.html nofilter}{* can not be escaped *}
</div>
{/if}
```

How can I change the content of $banner.html variable?

Comment: Which version of PrestaShop? What you have to do? Change what?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the .php file whose display banners.tpl
then, analyse variables are assign to smarty and change it !